# Modify slide show printout settings

Tags: stylesheet, slideshows

I am using the "Water" stylesheet for a slide show that has some problems when printing the slides as PDF, etc. When using e.g. ItemNumbered cells the item numbers get cropped at the left edge.

Does anybody knwo which style settings to adjust to keep the full cell visible?

To clarify the issue take the following minimal slide example (StyleSheet "Water")

[image]

Switching to Printout environment gives:

[image]
i